# select multiple rows from tow tables by duplicates of one table

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates

I want to list bestsellers

I have list of duplicates of sold products from table SALE and want to select those product properties from PRODUCT table

> my query to find duplicates from table SALE is:

```
SELECT product, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM sale
GROUP BY product
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT DESC
```

this query lists my `bestsellers products`, how to list these products properties from `PRODUCT` table in this order

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can just join in the product table:

```
SELECT p.product, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM product p JOIN
     sale s
     ON p.product = s.product
GROUP BY p.product
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT DESC ;
```

This assumes that `p.product` is the primary key on `PRODUCT` that links it to `SALES`.  Also, are you just counting "orders" or do you have a "quantity" field that you also care about?